# Front-end headline section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create the headline section on [www.dzn-studios.com](http://www.dzn-studios.com) full height, only when on desktop.

Though when I try and adjust the height: with a '%' value there is no effect. If I enter a pixel value that does change the height but ruins the responsiveness.

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VCfY.jpg)

Apologies for the newbie question but we all have to start somewhere right!

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike - I've tried to make the question make more sense. I can't include all the code because there are several .css files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would add this declarations to your css rule for header.section-headline.homepage

```
.section-headline.homepage {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Comment: When the browser width is less than 1100px the video does not cover the entire area - is there a quick way to fix this?

Comment: .section-headline.homepage video { background-size: cover; object-fit: cover; height: 100%; }

Comment: You cant set height of element to be height of window with percentages. You could do it with javascript and pixels, or with vh units; viewport height http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/viewport.html

Comment: Learned something new there - site looking much better now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

If I've understood your question correctly percentages aren't working.If this is the case you may need to set a 100% height on all your parent elements, in this case your body and html.

example:

`html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }`

`div { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`

if this isn't what you're asking please be more clear and i'll edit my answer

Comment: Thanks for the response, i'm trying to affect only the headline section. Similar to this www.internationalexecutiveevents.com

Comment: When I tried to change in google dev console, it came back with error stating can't use % on box-sizing: border-box; but the responsive grid it is built on is made up of border-boxes

Comment: I think I fixed it, you pointed me in the right direction it was sat in .pagewrapper with min-height: 100% - i changed it to height: 100%. That seemed to of worked? lol